# Comparison of an array of products using javascript, knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like any guidance or a starting point to implement a product comparator in out html5 knockout app. The comparator can add upto 3 products for comparison side by side, user has choice to remove any and add in a new product.

My problem is basically its easier to delete a div but how do i remove entire columns off in knockout?

for eg: 
        Prod1 x  Prod2 x    Prod3 x
col1    value1
col2             value2 
col3                        value3
etc..

Each of the x's is the delete. not quite used to posting here..please let me know in case of any queries. Thanks a lot again. Preferably I would like to create a template and let it handle the generation of the html..

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way, knockout is used to display your data model stored in a JS object.  Your requirements mean your data structure should be an array of objects `[{},{},{}]`, so your delete button should destroy that object from the main array leaving `[{},{}]`.  When knockout refreshes the view you'll not have that column anymore.  Remember that knockout is a replicator, so your hidden container acts as a template to create the others.  You won't make the containers the user sees, knockout will.

Comment: thanks for the above. I was wondering if the e commerce sites use some custom comparators..anyways i will give it a go the traditional way..

Answer (score 0):

Your columns can be divs (using float (probably better) or absolute positioning). I would prefer not to use knockout to repeat <TABLE> columns because you would need to use foreach in each table row to repeat the cells for each object in your data bound array. But this is possible.

Comment: thanks for the above. I was wondering if the e commerce sites use some custom comparators..anyways i will give it a go the traditional way..